# how to acces to other views inside a view definition in swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, swift4

when I want to reference a view inside other I got this error :

> value of type '(LoginController) -> () -> (LoginController)' has no
>   member 'userNameTF'

and here is my code :

```
class LoginController: UIViewController {
var userNameTF: UITextField = {
        let uName = UITextField()
        uName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        uName.textAlignment = .right
        uName.placeholder = "userName"
        uName.textColor = .gray
        uName.returnKeyType = .done
        return uName
    }()

private var contentView: MDCCard = {
        let view = MDCCard()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.cornerRadius = 0
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F2F2F2")
        view.setShadowElevation(ShadowElevation(rawValue: 6), for: .selected)
        view.setShadowColor(UIColor.black, for: .highlighted)
        view.addSubview(self.userNameTF)//here I call userNameTF}
}
```

my question is how to call `userNameTF` inside `contentView` ?

Comment: Where are you getting an error? which line?

Comment: @Augie I got Error  here {view.addSubview(self.userNameTF) } i cant add subview

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe contentview needs to be added to a view first?

Comment: @Augie thanks for your note but I think all encapsulations are right

Comment: yeah that before I knew where error was

Answer (score 0):

I changed some part of your code and it works. I just changed your custom view to UIView :

```
class LoginController: UIViewController {
    var userNameTF: UITextField = {
        let uName = UITextField()
        uName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        uName.textAlignment = .right
        uName.placeholder = "userName"
        uName.textColor = .gray
        uName.returnKeyType = .done
        return uName
    }()

    private var contentView: UIView  {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(self.userNameTF)
        return view
    }
}
```